# Problem running PyDev-developed apps in terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, terminal, pydev

Im having some import problems with an application I developed in python with Eclipse/PyDev.
Running the app from within Eclipse is no problem but when I try running it through the linux terminal the imports (which are imported from other folders (packages in Eclipse)) are broken and I get an ImportError: No module named xxx..

From previous experiences developing Java-apps in Eclipse I always solved this through exporting the project to a runnable jar-file but this isn't an option with Python.

Is there a way of circumventing this? I'd rather not put all my .py-files in a single folder since I very much like the package-system (guess Java has damaged me). Can I change the import statement to make it work in both Eclipse and the terminal or do I have to abandon PyDev if I want this to work in the terminal?

Thanks for any help!

Slim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that PyDev and Eclipse manage a custom Python Path when you're launching within Eclipse.  You can modify your environment variables to contain a more complete PYTHONPATH value that contains the locations where you're importing from, or you can use `sys.path.append()` to add directories to the path at run time so that the imports can be resolved.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want to do. I have however limited experience with Python. How would I go about this from lookin at this example:

folders A, B and Main with
main.py (the "run" file) in Main and imports from folders A and B

Comment: Well, I got the sys.path.append() to work but I'd rather go about it the other way of adding the paths from the terminal and not hard code them into my files

Comment: @Slim - There is some documentation regarding the search path available here:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path.  If you got `sys.path.append` to work then you're close it sounds like.  :)